# Подскажите новичку в javascript- как вставить значение из списка?

Tags: javascript, html

возможно ли при помощи чистого js реализовать функцию: по двойному клику на option из списка вставлять его значение в текстовое поле в котором до этого был курсор?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="text1" id="text1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="text2" id="text2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="text3" id="text3" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <select name="sel" id="sel" multiple>
        <option value="1">11111111</option>
        <option value="2">22222222</option>
        <option value="3">33333333</option>
        <option value="4">44444444</option>
        <option value="5">55555555</option>
    </select>
    <script>

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var lastArea;
document.getElementById('sel').addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
  if (lastArea) {
    lastArea.value += e.target.value + "\n";
  }
});
document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(i => i.addEventListener(
  'focus', function(e) { lastArea = this; }
));
```

```html
<textarea name="text1" id="text1" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea name="text2" id="text2" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<textarea name="text3" id="text3" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<select name="sel" id="sel" multiple>
  <option value="1">11111111</option>
  <option value="2">22222222</option>
  <option value="3">33333333</option>
  <option value="4">44444444</option>
  <option value="5">55555555</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АнтонБогданов Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.